# Value changes in all rows of matrix

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

so I decided to checkout the **Array.prototype.fill()** method and thus I've created a simple function that was supposed to return a matrix filled with either nulls or user chosen value.

My code for that looked like this:

```
function Matrix(x,y,value){
    if(value === undefined){
        value = null;
    }

    let arr = new Array(y);
    arr.fill(row());
    return arr;

    function row(){
        let subarr = new Array(x);
        subarr.fill(value);
        return subarr;
    }
}
```

And at first glance that worked pretty well. The problem occoured when I tried to reassign one of the values.

```
let arr = Matrix(5,5);

arr[2][2] = 'marked as duplicate';
console.log(arr);
```

I, of course, expected only one of the values to change but the output I got insted was this:

```
[ [ null, null, 'marked as duplicate', null, null, null, null ],
  [ null, null, 'marked as duplicate', null, null, null, null ],
  [ null, null, 'marked as duplicate', null, null, null, null ],
  [ null, null, 'marked as duplicate', null, null, null, null ],
  [ null, null, 'marked as duplicate', null, null, null, null ] ]
```

Could someone please explain to me why this is what happens?

Thanks.

Comment: You're filling the array with y copies of the same array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mate said, quoting **MDN**:

> The `fill()` method fills all the elements of an array from a start index to an end index with a static value.

Thence, your `"y"` array contains the same `"x"` array from the start to the end, because `row()` is evaluated only once, before the resulting array is used to fill the initial one.

Trying `console.log(arr[0] === arr[1]);` in your example will log `true` although you are expecting it to log `false`.

Here is a solution to your problem:

```
function Matrix(x, y, value) {
  if (!value) value = null;

  let arr = new Array(y);
  arr.fill(value);       // Fill with something just to be able to iterate
  return arr.map(row);   // build a new array with map() calling row() at
                             // each iteration
  function row() {
    let subArr = new Array(x);
    subArr.fill(value);
    return subArr;       // Return the sub-array to collect it with map()
  }
}

let arr = Matrix(5, 5);

arr[2][2] = 'marked as duplicate';
console.log(arr[0] === arr[1]);    // → Will log false
console.log(arr);        // Try the snippet below to see
```

---

---

**The snippet:**

```js
function Matrix(x, y, value) {
  if (!value) value = null;

  let arr = new Array(y);
  arr.fill(value);
  return arr.map(row);

  function row() {
    let subArr = new Array(x);
    subArr.fill(value);
    return subArr;
  }
}

let arr = Matrix(5, 5);

arr[2][2] = 'marked as duplicate';
console.log(arr[0] === arr[1]);
console.log(arr);
```

---

---

Answer (score 1):

From MDN's description of `Array.prototype.fill()` (emphasis mine):

> The fill() method fills all the elements of an array from a start
>   index to an end index with a **static value**.

In this line:

```
arr.fill(row());
```

`Array.fill()` won't invoke the `row()` method once for each element; it will invoke it *once*, and assigns that one result to each element of the array.

Comment: Thanks but I have to say it still kind of confuses me.

I'm aware of the fact that the function only runs once but shouldn't it behave normally after it's creation?

But ok, even when I consider that all of the values put in by **Fill** are literally the same value it still doesn't make sense to me. Because if that's the case then when I do, let's say:
`let arr = new Array(5); arr.fill(0);`
then when I do `arr[3] = 1;` shouldn't that also replace all of the values and give me `[1,1,1,1,1]`?

So why can I replace the column values with no problem but not the other way around?

Comment: This a longer topic: try reading up on *primitive values vs. reference values*. It's a very fundamental aspect of JavaScript's behavior and affects a lot of things besides arrays.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely check that out.